# Java installed, but "java -version" showed nothing, why?

Tags: java, version

I just bought a Win 7 PC, installed jdk1.6 and Netbeans, NB works fine, but when I did "java -version" in a command prompt, it can't find java, why ? How to fix it ?

Edit : I thought the installation process should set the path correctly, how come it didn't ?

Comment: The executable probably isn't in your path. What does 'echo %PATH%' say?

Comment: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\

Answer (score 5):

The JDK installer for windows does not update the path environment variable. The [installation docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/install-windows-152927.html) describe how to do this. See item #4 on that page.

Answer (score 2):

The path to `java` isn't in your system PATH variable.